# Play video in Activity with sliding up layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I'm writing an app where I want to stream video in loop with layouts sliding up to a 50% vertical mark. I also want to make a layout background white with transparency around 50-60%. I already found how to loop video, I have layouts that I need in separate activities and I have the animations slide up & down, what I'm confused is how to map my XML file layouts into a layouts list and how to call them to slide up and how to handle their inner events aka OnClick-s and so on.

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{


    private VideoView myVideoView;
    private MediaController mediaControls=null;
    private int position = 0;
    private String ppm_val=null;
    private TextView distance;
    private AdkReadTask mAdkReadTask;
    private int myInt = -10;
    private TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        buttonLED = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButtonLed);
        distance  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewIntro);
        buttonLED.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ppm);


        Animation slide_down = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                R.anim.slide_down);

        final Animation slide_up = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                R.anim.slide_up);



        myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        myVideoView.getHolder().setFixedSize(size.x, size.y);
        tv.setText(""+size.x+":"+size.y);

        try {
            //set the uri of the video to be played
            myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.test758));

        } catch (Exception e) {
//          Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
//          e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //we also set an setOnPreparedListener in order to know when the video file is ready for playback
        myVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

                mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
                myVideoView.seekTo(position);
                if (position == 0) {
                    myVideoView.start();
                } else {
                    //if we come from a resumed activity, video playback will be paused
                    myVideoView.pause();
                }
            }
        });

        if (((MyApplication) this.getApplication()).checkNull()) {
            ((MyApplication) this.getApplication()).init(this);
            ((MyApplication) this.getApplication()).open();

        }

        if (mAdkReadTask==null) {
            mAdkReadTask = new AdkReadTask();
            mAdkReadTask.execute();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ((MyApplication) this.getApplication()).write("1");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    public String output="";
    String[] sarr = new String[3];
    /* 
     * We put the readSerial() method in an AsyncTask to run the 
     * continuous read task out of the UI main thread
     */
    private class AdkReadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

        private boolean running = true;

        public void pause(){
            running = false;
        }
        public void start(){
            running = true;
        }
        private int cnt = 0;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            while(running) {


                if (this.isCancelled())
                    break;

                String s = ((MyApplication) getApplication()).read();
                if (s.charAt(0)=='R'){
                    running = false;
                }
                cnt++;
                publishProgress(s);
            }

            return output;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            if(progress[0].charAt(0)=='P') {
                tv.setText("Air quality: " + progress[0].substring(1, progress[0].length()));
                ppm_val = progress[0].substring(1, progress[0].length());
                ((MyApplication) getApplication()).setPPM(ppm_val);
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            next();
        }
    }

    private void next() {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, BuyRecycleActivity.class );
        new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                },
                1000);
    }

}
```

**slide_up.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0" />
</set>
```

**slide_down.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="100%" />
</set>
```

**EDIT 1:**
Code added. All I need is the way to put BuyRecycleActivity's layout to slide up form the bottom of main activity on 50%, while the video is still playing

Comment: put your code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using `include` layouts. Then setting them invisible by default.